# Access formControlName inside custom component

Tags: angular

Inputtypeformtext is our custom component. The purpose of this component is to display the textfield.

When I have the template within the component, I am able to able to see the values are getting tied with the fields.

```
    <input-type-form-text id="{{ question.value.questionId }}" [question]="question.value" 
    [form]="section">
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="isSelected"/>
     <input-form-error></input-form-error>
    </input-type-form-text>
```

If I move the inline template and kept inside the custom component template, I am not able to add the field values to the form

```
 <input-type-form-text id="{{ question.value.questionId }}" [question]="question.value" 
    [form]="section">
    </input-type-form-text>
```

Inside the custom component template

```
<div class="screen-input-text-field dynamic-field form-group" [formGroup]="form">

      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="isSelected"/>
             <input-form-error></input-form-error>
</div>
```

How to access or pass the formControlName inside the custom component.
Can someone help on this.

Comment: Since you're passing in your formGroup down to the child component, you just need to append the formControl to the formGroup, then your parent component should be able to grab the form control via the formGroup

Answer (score 1):

In order to access Reactive Form formcontrolname inside your own custom component, your custom component needs to implement ControlValueAccessor Interface.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'input-selectcontrol-form',
  templateUrl: '',
  styleUrls: [''],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => SelectFormControlComponent)
    }
  ]
})
export class SelectFormControlComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() dropDownList;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value) {}

  }

  propagateChange(time: any) {
    console.log(time);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}
}
```

ReferenceLink : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/angular-custom-form-control-controlvalueaccessor-ankit-rana

https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83